# How to disable checkbox in a specific table row after clicking a button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I already have a code that works in disabling enabling elements after clicking a button. However, disabling a checkbox using `addClass("disabled")` is not working. How would I do that? Please take a look with my code below. Thanks a lot.

`td:nth-child(3)` and `td:nth-child(4)` is working fine but `td:nth-child(1)` checkbox disable is not working.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.generate', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

          var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),

              $tds1 = $row.find("td:nth-child(1) input[type=checkbox].loan-id-checkbox").addClass("disabled");

              $tds3 = $row.find("td:nth-child(3) a.generate").addClass("disabled");
              $tds4 = $row.find("td:nth-child(4) a.btn-showAmort").removeClass("disabled");

      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable a checkbox use the attribute `disabled`. The css class will not have an effect.

```
$tds1 = $row.find("td:nth-child(1) input[type=checkbox].loan-id-checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't just need to addClass for checkbox you need to set attribute to true for disabling the checkbox like this.

```
 $row.find("td:nth-child(1) input[type=checkbox].loan-id-checkbox").addClass("disabled", true);
 OR
 $row.find("td:nth-child(1) input[type=checkbox].loan-id-checkbox").addClass("disabled",false)
```